# iphone background scale issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a background image being placed by the following:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"v3_bg.png"]];
```

However, my image, which is 960x640 does not scale correctly when i run the simulator, in both v3 and v4 of the iphone. Could some one please help explain to me why the iphone simulator 4 does'nt use the full size of the image, it seems to only just scale up what the v3 displays.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Simulator, go to Hardware>Device and select iPhone(Retina) rather than iPhone.